# How to find all groups of rows that exist in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find groups of rows where all the members are in another group or table.  Oddly, I'm even having a hard time explaining this succinctly in technical terms.  This is a contrived example, but should show what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'd like to find the parents where all of their children are named after Bible characters.

```
CREATE TABLE BibleNames (Name varchar(20) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE ChildNames (ParentName varchar(20) NOT NULL, ChildName varchar(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO BibleNames (Name) VALUES ('David'),('Adam'),('Deborah'),('Ruth'),('Maria'),('Timothy');
INSERT INTO ChildNames (ParentName, ChildName) VALUES
('Parent1','David'),
('Parent1','Adam'),
('Parent2','Ronnie'),
('Parent2','Ruth'),
('Parent3','Maria'),
('Parent4','Axl'),
('Parent4','Justin');
```

I have accomplished this task using this code, and it works, but it feels wrong, and it feels like I'm probably missing something native within SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
  ParentName
FROM ChildNames c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BibleNames b
    ON c.ChildName = b.Name
GROUP BY ParentName
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN b.Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
select distinct parentname
from childnames c1
where not exists(select * from childnames c2 
             where c1.parentname = c2.parentname and
                   not exists(select * from biblename where name = c2.childname)
```

Comment: This is actually bring back the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish, but I have always had a sneaking suspicion that the EXIST approach is what I should be using....just not sure how to use it correctly in this scenario.

Comment: @SumOfDavid, yes, I have edited. First exists also needs `not` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written this using windowed COUNT(*). It does a simple `LEFT JOIN` and compares counts between names returned from different tables. If their counts match - parents should have all of their children with bible names.

```
;WITH CTE(ParentName, ChildName, BibleName, BN, CN)
AS (
  SELECT CN.ParentName
    , CN.ChildName
    , BN.Name
    , COUNT(CN.ChildName) OVER (PARTITION BY CN.ParentName)
    , COUNT(BN.Name) OVER (PARTITION BY CN.ParentName)
  FROM #ChildNames AS CN
  LEFT JOIN #BibleNames AS BN
    ON BN.Name = CN.ChildName
  )
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS C
WHERE C.BN = C.CN;
```

For your data it brings back this result:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════╦═════╗
║ ParentName ║ ChildName ║ BibleName ║ BN ║ CN  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════╬═════╣
║ Parent1    ║ David     ║ David     ║  2 ║   2 ║
║ Parent1    ║ Adam      ║ Adam      ║  2 ║   2 ║
║ Parent3    ║ Maria     ║ Maria     ║  1 ║   1 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════╩═════╝
```

There should be more ways to do this. It's quite simple query, if being honest. It's just a matter of taste how to write it.

Comment: This works, although I'm not sure this is better than my original example.  While I understand it, it does seem to be a tad bit more complicated.

Comment: Only advantage I see is that it brings not only parents, but their children names too. But of that's not the requirement, your original query might be better. Both are quite easy to understand.